# Need pandas groupby.count() or groupby.size.unstack() to output a dataframe I can use

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, count, pivot

So I need to count the number of occurrences of a value per year, per animal. I've managed to do it but it's outputting a single column kind of dataframe rather than the data being in workable cells.

I've used:

```
df.groupby(["Animal", "year"])["value"].count()
```

and:

```
df.groupby(["Animal", "year", "value"]).size().unstack(fill_value=0)
```

and I tried a pivot but it gave an error, in the error message it said too much data but the main error was "Index contains duplicate entries". I've about 13000 rows of data.

I have no idea what to do with the response. I can't call the columns like you would with a Dataframe, I don't know how to. I want to be able to create proportions, like value A is 10% and value B is 90% for animal 1 for year 2020, in a Dataframe.

I tried to do `df.to_frame()` after the `count()` created a series, one but it just created a one column DataFrame.

The data is like:

```
Animal  Year Value
1       2020  A
1       2020  A
1       2019  B
1       2019  B
2       2020  A
```

And I need it to be:

```
Animal   Year  A  B
 1       2020  2  0
 1       2019  0  2
 2       2020  1  0
```

But in a full proper Dataframe of 4 columns, not squished into one column. Then I can create the % proportions from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```py
x = df.pivot_table(
    index=["Animal", "Year"], columns="Value", aggfunc="size", fill_value=0
).reset_index()
x.columns.name = None
print(x)
```

Prints:

```
   Animal  Year  A  B
0       1  2019  0  2
1       1  2020  2  0
2       2  2020  1  0
```

Comment: Thanks! That has printed it out into the correct format, but it's still not a dataframe. How do I turn the output into a dataframe?

Comment: @Phoenix What `print(type(x))` says?

Comment: <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>

Comment: Ah! It's because I was using print(x) instead of x.head() that it appears differently so I thought it was like the previous ones where the columns were merged. It's a perfectly fine dataframe, all is well. Problem solved.